# uninitialized constant GamesController::GamesAccounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

created a games_account.rb file in the library folder. The following is the structure

```
module GamesAccounts
    class GamesAccountsClient
.
.
.
.
.
end
 end
```

trying to do GamesAccounts::GamesAccountsClient.new in the controller gives me the error

```
uninitialized constant GamesController::GamesAccounts
```

I have even added

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib) in the applications.rb
```

Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Please don't autoload `lib/`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this, but I think you might need to put it in `lib/games_accounts/games_accounts_client.rb` instead of what you have now, which I presume is `lib/games_account.rb`. The idea is it should be `lib/<module name>/<class name>.rb`.

Comment: Separate thought: I'd question why you'd want to put your class in `lib`. It very well may be appropriate to put your class in `app/models/`. Just because something is a model doesn't mean it has to inherit from ActiveRecord or have anything to do with the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your file, name it **games_accounts.rb** instead of **games_account.rb** and it should work (because it will match the module name).

If you plan to put many classes within this module, create a directory named games_accounts, and add the class there with the mapping of each file to each class, and put it on your **application.rb** file, like

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/games_accounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a other thought, If your file is something which is be helping the models than try having it in the form of concerns folder and adding your file there.  Since Rails 4 onwards all these support activities will be taken by concerns it's good to adopt right away.  Have a read at the blog post by DHH also:

http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns